# How do I handle ampersand encoding in Report Builder?

Tags: reporting-services, ibm-midrange, report-builder2.0

I have a Select statement that combines multiple rows into 1 result row using FOR XML PATH in Report Builder 2.0.  I am pulling the data from an IBM i520 server.  When a row has an ampersand in it I get a &  How do I clean this up in my select statement ?

```
SELECT CAST(Q5TXLN + ' ' AS VARCHAR(MAX))FROM 520SERVER WHERE Q5$CPN = @pdCustNo AND Q5TP = 'PDS' FOR XML PATH ('')
```

Comment: An ampersand is a &.  Could you edit the question with some sample data?  Show what you are getting and what you want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select
REPLACE(
cast((SELECT CAST(replace(Q5TXLN,'&','#') + ' ' AS VARCHAR(MAX))FROM [520SERVER] WHERE Q5$CPN = @pdCustNo AND Q5TP = 'PDS' FOR XML PATH (''),type) as varchar(max))
,'#','&')
```